# Guidelines to choose between relative risk and absolute risk

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, case-control-study, relative-risk, absolute-risk

I have a regular case-control study where I can calculate the proportion of patients infected when exposed to say, UV vs regular light. For hypothesis testing, how do I decide which is a better measure - relative risk or absolute risk? I found this answer with comparison of the two approaches - [How do you explain the difference between relative risk and absolute risk?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29614/how-do-you-explain-the-difference-between-relative-risk-and-absolute-risk)

However, there were no guidelines on how to choose the right approach. Could you please help?

Comment: You cannot calculate either measure in a case-control study; you can only calculate an odds ratio.  So please clarify.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't come from a stats background. And my problem is not in epidemiology. But for each group, I have exact information about the number of subjects infected, out of total number of subjects in the study. I want to compare the two groups. I can calculate the ratio and difference of the proportion of subjects infected. Maybe there is another name for this problem. Please guide.

Comment: Study the different study designs.  Case-control designs involve outcome-dependent sampling.  With such retrospective designs you can't calculate certain quantities.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks for the advice, Frank. However, I would be grateful for a little more details. Also, if you could recommend some reading - books or research papers, that will be helpful.

Comment: See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio